# Android: Saved File on external storage is only shown after restarting phone

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-external-storage

I want to save a .txt file to my external storage with this code:

```
String exportTitle = etTitle.getText().toString();
String exportContent = etContent.getText().toString();
noteExporter.run(exportTitle, exportContent);
```

And this:

```
public void run(String title, String content){

        if(isExternalStorageWritable()) {

            try {
                File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + title + ".txt");
                Boolean append = file.createNewFile();

                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file, append);
                OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(fos);
                writer.append(content);

                writer.close();
                fos.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("ERROR", e.toString());
            }
        }
    }
```

The File is saved on the external storage, but I can only see it on my phone after restarting my phone. I'm using Android Studio and use my phone as testing device. Questions has been ask before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31188527/as3-for-android-saving-a-file-in-the-external-storage-only-visible-when-phone), but not answered.

Comment: I posted an answer, but might not work for you, please let me know in comment, so I can remove it then.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32789157/how-to-write-files-to-external-public-storage-in-android-so-that-they-are-visibl

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks, this worked!